# How to convert variable of type Any object to String when this variable contains Null in iOS?

Tags: json, swift

The problem is when I want to cast user variable to string, it says `unable to read data`. It might be because the user object contains null.

### Response:

```
SUCCESS: {
    data =     {
        user =         {
            email = "<null>";
            firstName = "<null>";
        };

        //... 
    };
    message = "";
    messageCode = "API_200";
}
```

### Code:

```
if let responseDict = response["data"] as? [String : AnyObject] {

    if let user = responseDict["user"] {
       if let userString = user as? String
       {
          var itIsExtracted = true;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Blame the owner of the website to send real `null` values, not a *stringyfied* null because `null` can easily be deserialized to `nil`. And JSON objects are never `AnyObject` in Swift 3+, they are `Any`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I can see is that your `user`-object is declared as an `Any`. Try to set it as a dictionary.

```
guard let responseDict = response["data"] as? [String : Any],
    let user = responseDict["user"] as? [String : Any] else {
        // There is no user
        return
}

if let userEmail = user["email"] as? String {
    print(userEmail)
    // Can be a result as "<null>" because of server result
}
if let firstName = user["firstName"] as? String {
    print(firstName)
    // Can be a result as "<null>" because of server result
}
```

I can also add what @Vadian said. Blame the owner of the website to send real null values, not a stringified null.